# Filtered colim of F-groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, limits-and-colimits

A group G is said to have a property F if there exists a finite aspherical CW-complex of which it is the fundamental group (according to wikipedia).

question: is there a full characterization of groups that are obtained as a filtered colimits of F-groups?

Thanks.

**Edit:** May be more simple (?) question: Is any torsion free group a filtered colimit of F-groups?

Comment: I'm not sure what a full characterization would look like, but this feels like a pretty broad class of groups. For example it includes every torsion-free nilpotent group, every torsion-free lacunary hyperbolic group, and of course all F-groups (of which there are already a lot). Just pointing out those examples.

Comment: For the simpler question, did you try the countably infinite direct product of ${\mathbb Z}$'s?

Comment: For the simpler question, I think any finitely presented torsion-free group that is not itself an F-group should be a counterexample (so like, Thompson's group $F$). Since it's finitely presented it can't be a filtered colimit in an "interesting" way (errr right? Is that how filtered colimits work?), so would have to just be an F-group itself already, which it's not.

Comment: @MoisheKohan no, I did not.

Comment: @MattZaremsky I don't really understand your second comment.

Comment: Let me say the second comment better. I claim Thompson's group $F$ (which is torsion-free) is not a filtered colimit of F-groups. Say it is the filtered colimit of some $(G_i)_i$ for the $G_i$ all F-groups. Then since $F$ is finitely presented it must be isomorphic to a subgroup of one of the $G_i$ (this is assuming what you're calling "filtered colimit" is the same as what I usually see called "direct limit", which I think is right, but I guess I'm not positive). But $F$ contains $\mathbb{Z}^\infty$ and so is not isomorphic to a subgroup of any F-group, a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer to the simpler question, "Is any torsion free group a filtered colimit of F-groups?" (Or, just to be clear, let me rephrase the question as, "Is *every* torsion free group a filtered colimit of F-groups?")

The answer is no: Thompson's group $F$ is torsion free but I claim it is not a filtered colimit of F-groups. Let $G$ be the colimit of some filtered system of groups $(G_i)$, so as explained in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362502/finitely-generated-subgroups-of-direct-limits-of-groups every finitely presented subgroup of $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $G_j$ for some $j$ (note that this is assuming what you call "filtered colimit" is the same as what is called "direct limit" in this link; from doing a little research it seems this is the case). Now suppose $G=F$, which since $F$ itself is finitely presented tells us that $F$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $G_j$ for some $j$. Lastly, suppose all the $G_i$ are F-groups, so we get that $F$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of some F-group. This is a contradiction since $F$ contains $\mathbb{Z}^\infty$ but no F-group can contain $\mathbb{Z}^\infty$. We conclude $F$ is not a filtered colimit of any system of F-groups.

Note that this argument is not really that specific to $F$; it shows that any finitely presented subgroup of a filtered colimit of F-groups must be isomorphic to a subgroup of an F-group. In particular the class "finitely presented groups embeddable into a filtered colimit of F-groups" coincides with the class "finitely presented groups embeddable into an F-group".

Comment: Filtered colimit is more general then directed ones. Take a look in nlab !

Comment: Oh...wait, really? Hmm, nlab is actually exactly where I got this from: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/direct+limit "A direct limit is the same thing as a colimit.... Many authors restrict this terminology to...filtered colimit[s]." Anyway, hopefully for whatever notion of filtered colimit you're dealing with this general strategy works.

Comment: Every filtered category has a cofinal map from a filtered poset, so for the purposes of this question the distinction is immaterial